# Move DRBD device to different underlying device without need of re-sync?

Tags: debian, drbd, luks

I have a pretty large DRBD device connected through WAN. It is a bout 2TB in size and the change rate of the data is pretty low.

It is configured on devices as follows:

- VirtIO disk (*.img) on QNAP virtualization
- Used as /dev/vdb inside the Debian VM
- On top of vdb there is a LUKS-encryption layer
- Above then there is DRBD device
- finally, filesystem is btrfs

On one of the nodes I need to remove the encryption layer. How can I do this without the need of syncing all data from scratch? Is it fine to create a new virtual disk (*img) and "dd" the drbd-device to it? Like `dd if=/dev/drbd0 of=/dev/vdc`, re-configure the device in /etc/drbd* accordingly and live happily ever after?

Thanks for your input!

/KNEBB

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I had it wrong in mind. DRBD is below the enrcypted layer. The correct order is as follows:

- VirtIO disk (*.img) on QNAP virtualization
- Used as /dev/vdb inside the Debian VM
- On top of vdb there is the DRBD device
- Above then there is a LUKS-encryption layer
- finally, filesystem is btrfs

So there is no change to do it without full resync because the existing data is stored encrypted on the DRBD. I can easily remove the encrpyted layer threough btrfs operations. But it will write in any case the data new to the drbd device leading close to a full resync.

Damn....